# UNUserNotificationCenter: Is it possible to intercept a local notification before display when the app is in the background or closed?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, notifications

I've looked and looked but so far I haven't found the answer, so it's time to ask here.

AFAIK, when the application is in the background or closed, a scheduled local notification that is due will just display (per the notification settings for the app -- .alert, .badge, .sound) but no method call will be made at that time.  Only when the user handles the notification will the **didReceive** method run.

OTOH, if the application is in the foreground, the **willPresent** method call will fire, so you can handle the notification before displaying it to the user, or dismiss it altogether.

I'm looking for a way to intercept the notification before displaying it to the user **when the application is in the background or closed**. IOW, the local notification arrives, certain conditions are checked after which the local notification is delivered or not (just like while in the foreground).

...or just wake the application and let the app handle things from there, but somehow intercept that background local notification before being displayed.

From the source: [Local and Remote Notifications Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH3-SW1), [Scheduling and Handling Local Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH5-SW1) and [Modifying and Presenting Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ModifyingNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH16-SW1).

I've found nothing.  Is this possible?

Perhaps this can be done with push notifications... but I haven't found how to schedule the notification from the client to the remote server, so then at the scheduled time the server pushes the notification and it can be intercepted via a notification extension, for handling and display or dismissal as necessary.

Comment: I think you're going to need some server side implementation to schedule a silent push notification which would allow you to incept it and display a local notification if needed. Perhaps you could use some intermediate push service like Pushwoosh which would allow you to easily schedule notifications. At the time your app would have scheduled the local notification, it would instead call a very simple backend api which would then call Pushwoosh or similar to schedule the push notification for that fire date/time

Comment: You're right! There is no any methods will be called! You can handle the local notifications with the user interactions. And only willPresent method will be called without user interactions while the app is foreground. Good luck

Comment: Well, decided to try push notifications via Firebase to test the interception of the notification via a service extension, and after setting up Firebase in my project and successfully receiving push notifications now it turns out my service extension never gets called because Firebase doesn't support the mutable-content key which is required for triggering the extension.  My quest continues...

Comment: do you actually need the service extension? I haven't worked with firebase or service extensions before but I have done similar to what you need to do before and I did not need a service extension

Comment: @Simon: I am coming to the same conclusion since notification can be handled either in the didReceiveRemoteNotification or in the remote handler for the specific service you are using.  In my case, I found that OneSignal better fit my requirements.  However, no matter what I've tried, none of it works if the application isn't running; it has to be at least in the background. So what did you do to intercept the remote notification when the app is killed/not running?

Comment: I ended up something similar to what Simon suggested so I'm going to mark his response as the correct answer.  Thank you.